# Why sometime control does not go to the event when it is click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used the following code. This code works sometime but sometime not works. Please explain the resion and modify the code.

.aspx page:

```
<td valign="top" align="left" width="10px" runat="server" id="tdNoteRightBar">
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidNoteId" Value='<%# Eval("PK_ID").ToString() %>' />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnAddToPin" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/pin_addto.png"
      OnClick="ibtnAddToPin_Click" ToolTip="Pin this note to stay on top." Style="padding-right: 1px;" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnPinMarkedRemovePin" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/pin_marked.png"
      Visible="false" OnClick="ibtnPinMarkedRemovePin_Click" Style="padding-top: 2px;" />
</td>
```

.cs page

```
    protected void ibtnAddToPin_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)(((ImageButton)sender).Parent.Parent);
            int noteId = Convert.ToInt32(((HiddenField)dataItem.FindControl("hidNoteId")).Value);

            Notes.PinANote(noteId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);

            lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblError.Text = "Error occurred while pinning the note.";
        }
    }

    protected void ibtnPinMarkedRemovePin_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)(((ImageButton)sender).Parent.Parent);
            int noteId = Convert.ToInt32(((HiddenField)dataItem.FindControl("hidNoteId")).Value);

            Notes.UnPinANote(noteId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);

            lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblError.Text = "Error occurred while un pinning the note.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're welcome. To learn how to format your posts so they show up properly, see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Can anyone modify the code, so that it works properly.........

Comment: @SHALINI: Wheter u overcome your problem?

Comment: Ya....I fixed that issue.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Shalini Pls check whether you provides any validation controls?.I think some times when it works that condition satisfies and not works when validation fails.So pls check the controls.Add property `Validation Group="abc"`  to the controls which requries some validation.and try again.

Comment: There is no validation control with the imagebutton. SO whom to give the validation group???

Comment: try to give CausesValidation="false" and give some Validation Group="abc" where abc is not there. Also check whether in your .aspx page[where javascripts resides] is der any portion like <script runat="server" language="C#"><here may be code for your click belongs <script/>

Answer (score 0):

Is the AutoPostback property set to true?
Are there any javascript error in the page.
If there is any, the post back may not happen.

Comment: There is no property like AutoPostback  in case of imagebutton. Then how to check the Autopostback property.

Comment: Autopost back is @ page level. in Page directive. And what about javascript errors